# Как генерировать комбинацию клавиш ALT+B?

Tags: java, android, клавиатура

Как генерировать комбинацию клавиш ALT+B ? То есть чтоб при нажатии на кнопку, например Вверх, система поняла бы нажатие комбинации кнопок ALT и B ?